# PHP - Call javascript from server side

Tags: javascript, php, web-services

Is there anyway to run / trigger / call a javascript (client side) from server side (PHP) ?

I can run the javascript if i call it from browser (of course, because it's client), but not from server side / postman (i wonder if there's any?)

```
function validate_answer($p) {
?>

<script>
    $.ajax({ url: '/validate_time.php',
     data: {'action': 'test'},
     type: 'post',
     timeout:5000
    });
</script>

<?php
```

}

The reason i want to use this way, because in PHP, there's no such function like setTimeout like javascript does.

Thanks guys

**EDIT**

Okay, here's the thing.
I'm creating a game that has a timeout, whenever the game starts, it will have a timelimit (10 mins example). And i need a function to do that, unfortunately, it's not accessible via browser (it's like a web service). I've tried using sleep, but it's not what i wanted.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: you could use php sleep

Comment: hi @u_mulder, as i said above, i need it because in php there's no such thing like settimeout (javascript). Sleep isnt the same like settimeout. it will not execute other stuff until it wake up.

Comment: Why do you need timeout on server?

Comment: @Ryad.iv, i need to do some stuff . if I use sleep(5), it wont do any stuff, until it wake up

Comment: This can be done with cronjobs.

Comment: To be able to actively contact and interact with the client side you need some form of persistent connection. Reason is the network topology, you typically cannot send a package to the client. You have two options: long polling ajax calls or web sockets. You will find examples for both approaches.

Comment: Try to check `GearmanWorker::setTimeout` function. This may help you. Here is the link http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.settimeout.php

Comment: PHP **sleep()** maybe useful to you , try with that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run javascript on the server side. If you want to get the effect of the timeout without holding up your main script, you can call the URL with a parameter like this:

```
function validate_answer($p) {

    $ms_delay = 5000;

    file_get_contents('http://www.yoursite.com/validate_time.php?action=test&delay='.$ms_delay)

}
```

And then in validate_time.php at the start of the file do this:

```
sleep($_GET['delay'] / 1000)
```

Not very elegant though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is single-threaded, and in general PHP is focused on the HTTP request cycle, so this would be tricky to allow a timeout to run code, potentially after the request is done.

I can suggest you look into [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.settimeout.php) as a solution to delegate work to other PHP processes.

Comment: Hi, i will try it, and will update the result. thanks :)